# Upload photo on friend/fan page with Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, photo

I want to upload a foto from my android app to a facebook fan page using the facebook API.

When i look in the hackbook android example app ([link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/)). the code looks as following to a upload photo:

```
Bundle params = new params.putString("url",
"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg");                            params.putString("caption",
    "FbAPIs Sample App photo upload");

Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params,
    "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

This code works, it posts the photo on my own facebook page. But i don't want the photo to be posted on my page but on a fan page.

As explained in the facebook documentation 'me' could be changed with a facebook User_ID. I tried changing the "me/photo" in "[fanpagename]/photo" or "[fanpageID]/photo", but that did not work. when i used the username i got an error, when i used the ID it post the photo on my own page. In the graphAPI photo documentation ([link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)) no example or explanation is givin on how to upload a foto on fan page.

also the

```
params.putString("to", [fbid]);
```

does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been busy with this research for three full days and did not find the answer for my problem. But i think i have an explanation for it.

if a user posts a photo to friend/fan_page with the official android FB app it uses a "feed" with a picture(url-link). The user can't see on his own wall that he actually shared or posted a picture on the friend/fan_page. (for example: "Bob - posted a photo on CocaCola")

This is probably the reason why the function is disabled because developers could use this to send photo's to all kinds of friends/fan_pages without the user being aware of it.

I came to this hypotheses because i found a sort of work around. First upload the photo to users own album. get the URL of that photo and then post a "feed" on the friend/fan_page with a picture(url-lnk). Facebook then gave this error: "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream" in other words, you can't use photos that are on FB website domain to link to. So I think there is quite a bug/lazyness in the facebook developement departmet :P which is a pity because it is a nice socialnetworking function for mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but to publish photos to a Page you will need the `publish_stream` and `manage_pages` permissions, and the Page Access Token to prove you have them. You can read more about this here:

1. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos
2. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens

Some example code (using the PHP SDK, but the logic should be the same in any language) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222078/164439

Update:

If you want to post to the Page's *Wall/Feed* (without being a Page Admin), you can do that without the Manage Pages permission and the Access Token stuff.

But it's different than publishing a Photo object to the Page's *Photos* collection, which is what I thought you asked. You actually want to do a regular Post to the Page, with a Picture attachment.

Here are some resources to do this:

1. Facebook Post API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
2. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile
3. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5756474/post-to-facebook-page-wall
4. [Using Facebook Graph to simply post a wall message with just javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724977/using-facebook-graph-to-simply-post-a-wall-message-with-just-javascript)

Good luck!

Comment: You get the Page access token with the `/me/accounts` API call, then you use that token instead of your regular user token. (Just add `access_token=` to your call to override the default token)

Comment: I think what you actually want to do is post an image to their Feed, which is actually just creating a Post with a Picture attachment. I added some links to help with that. Cheers

Comment: thaddeusmt -  Unfortunately posting a wall post only works when having a photo link(String). The params "photo/picture/source" is expected to be a String(picture link adres) not a ByteArray(local picture). i Do succeed in posting a WallPost on a page so no Manage_pages or Page_access tokens are 

required indeed. Posting a photo on a page wall/album just can not be done with an android app. But it should because it is possible with the Official Facebook App! so if anyone finds out how, please let me know! thaddeusmt thanks for all the help and information you have provided!