# Post to Facebook page as the page itself, not user

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

I need to post to my FB page as the page, not as myself. I saw some codes but they seem to be outdated. If you could offer some help that would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Which framework? Are you using the PHP-sdk or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

To impersonate pages your user needs to have manage_pages permission.

Then use [stream.publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) - below example with PHP-SDK.

```
stream_publish($message, $attachment = null, 
               $action_links = null, $target_id = null, 
               $uid = $YOUR_PAGE_UID_HERE)
```

Comment: I will use this myself. It's gonna be a script run via cron. That's why I need it to autentificate itself and then do the job.

Comment: you can run PHP via cron if server properly configured. The user must still have the correct permissions. See php example here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009352/facebook-post-on-page-with-php-sdk

Comment: I am unable to use the code you provided. So basically I authorize the app, then I connect to the app and how do I switch from "me" to "FB page x"? Also, after I am authenticated as Page, how can I save the login credentials to be able to use them later? I want to use cron to post automatically to the page as the page. I am using the  PHP-sdk.

Comment: you will need the offline access-permission as well... See this bloggpost http://akcora.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/php-facebook-cronjob-with-offline-access/